# How to calculate employees working hours on weekwise in Tsql

Tags: t-sql

How to calculate Total working hours of employees on weekly wise.

```
employee    week1   week2   week3   week4
rams         50      48       49     54
```

Comment: Is that the output you require? If so, what is your db schema containing the raw data?

Comment: yeah. based on working hours of employee. @AdaTheDev

Comment: Please provide the source data and it's table structure.

Comment: Nothing on Google about how to SUM a column?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the structure of your table makes it difficult but if it's similar to this below: then you can use pivot with dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @dynamicSql AS nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @dynamicCols AS nvarchar(max);


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempHours') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tempHours

CREATE TABLE #tempHours (
  empId int,
  workDate datetime,
  hoursWorked money
)

INSERT INTO #temphours
  VALUES (1, '1/2/2016', 8.5)
INSERT INTO #temphours
  VALUES (2, '2/3/2016', 8.5)
INSERT INTO #temphours
  VALUES (3, '3/4/2016', 8.5)
INSERT INTO #temphours
  VALUES (4, '4/5/2016', 8.5)
INSERT INTO #temphours
  VALUES (5, '5/6/2016', 8.5)

INSERT INTO #temphours
  VALUES (1, '1/3/2016', 8.5)
INSERT INTO #temphours
  VALUES (1, '1/4/2016', 8.5)
INSERT INTO #temphours
  VALUES (2, '2/4/2016', 8.5)
INSERT INTO #temphours
  VALUES (3, '3/5/2016', 8.5)
INSERT INTO #temphours
  VALUES (4, '4/6/2016', 8.5)
INSERT INTO #temphours
  VALUES (5, '5/7/2016', 8.5)



-- Construct the column list for the IN clause
SET @dynamicCols = STUFF((SELECT
  N',' + QUOTENAME(w) AS [text()]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
  DATEPART(wk, workDate) AS W
FROM #temphours) AS W
ORDER BY W
FOR xml PATH (''))
,
1, 1, N'');


-- Construct the full T-SQL statement
-- and execute dynamically

SET @dynamicSql = N'SELECT *
            FROM (SELECT empId, datepart(wk,workDate) as WeekNo, hoursWorked
                    FROM dbo.#temphours) AS I
            PIVOT(SUM(hoursWorked) FOR WeekNo IN(' + @dynamicCols + N')) AS P;';

EXEC sp_executesql @dynamicSql;

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [SUM()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) this will get you there.

```
SELECT Color, SUM(ListPrice), SUM(StandardCost)  
    FROM Production.Product  
    WHERE Color IS NOT NULL   
        AND ListPrice != 0.00   
        AND Name LIKE 'Mountain%'  
    GROUP BY Color  
    ORDER BY Color;  
GO
```

I believe that a little more info in the question will get you better answers.